# Delay Mocha test programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm familiar with Mocha's support of [delaying the root suite](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite) to enable performing asynchronous operations before a test is executed, by use of running Mocha with the `--delay` flag, but this impacts all tests.

Is it possible to do something like this on a test by test basis, without using the `--delay` flag?

An example of a working asynchronous test is below, but unfortunately not of all of our tests are async and call `run()`. Please note that the below example also leverages [dynamically generating tests](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests) to generate a test for each URL that is detected during the asynchronous operation before the suite executes.

```
driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
await driver.get('http://example.org');
await driver.findElements(By.css('article header a')).then(async function (anchors) {
    Promise.all(
        anchors.map(async anchor => {
            return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
                try {
                    const href = await anchor.getAttribute('href');
                    urls.push(href);
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('Catch')
                    reject(err);
                }
            })
        })
    ).then(function () {
        driver.quit();
        describe('my suite', function () {
            urls.forEach(function (url) {
                it(`Loads ${url}`, async function () {
                    await driver.get(url);
                    await driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                        assert.strictEqual(1, 1);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        run();
    })
});
```

Following @destroyer's suggestion, I was successful in accomplishing something similar using [asynchronous hooks](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-hooks) (below), but cannot dynamically generate a separate test for each URL since Mocha does not delay the root suite execution.

```
describe('Async test suite', function () {
    const getAnchors = function () {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
            await driver.get('http://example.org');
            await driver.findElements(By.css('article header a'))
                .then(async (anchors) => {
                    resolve(anchors);
                })
        });
    }

    const getUrls = function (anchors) {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
                urls.push(await anchors[i].getAttribute('href'));

                if (i === (anchors.length - 1)) {
                    resolve(urls);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    const iterateUrls = function (urls) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                await driver.get(urls[i])
                const thisUrl = await driver.getCurrentUrl();
                try {
                    await assert.strictEqual(thisUrl, urls[i]);
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);

                    break;
                }

                if (i === (urls.length - 1)) {
                    resolve();
                }
            }
        })
    }

    async function asyncController() {
        Promise.all([
            anchors = await getAnchors(),
            await getUrls(anchors)
        ])
    }

    // Trigger async functions here
    before(function (done) {
        asyncController()
            .then(() => {
                done();
            })
    });

    // Close the browser after test completes
    after(async function () {
        await driver.quit()
    });

    describe('Checks URLs', function () {
        it('Iterates over URLs', async function (done) {
            try {
                await iterateUrls(urls);
            } catch (err) {
                done(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you running mocha with the `--delay` flag?

Comment: @destoryer Thanks, yes I am. I've edited my initial question to hopefully further clarify what I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: Have you considered using an [asynchronous hook](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-hooks)?

Comment: Thanks again. I thought I had tried that, but will attempt it again.